# Angular 2 RC1 - Updating parent component property from child route component property

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

**App Component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: '<div class="heading">{{heading}}</div>'
})
@Routes([
    {path: '/comp1', component: Comp1Component},
    {path: '/comp2', component: Comp2Component}
])
export class AppComponent {
    heading: string = 'App Component';
}
```

**Comp1Component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'comp1'
})
export class Comp1Component {
    // how to change heading property of app component from here
    // Want to change heading property of AppComponent to "Component 1"
}
```

**Comp2Component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'comp2'
})
export class Comp2Component {
    // how to change heading property of app component from here
    // Want to change heading property of AppComponent to "Component 2"
}
```

I want to update **heading** property of AppComponent based on routes selected?

Can anyone suggest me is it possible with Angular2 RC 1 ? And how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your safe bet is to use a service:

**DataService.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    ...
    heading: string;
    ...
    setHeading(newValue) {
        this.heading = newValue; //you can also do validation or other things here
    }
    getHeading() {
        return this.heading;
    }
    ...
}
```

**AppComponent.ts**

```
import {DataService} from './DataService';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    providers: [DataService],
    template: '<div class="heading">{{heading}}</div>'
})
@Routes([
    {path: '/comp1', component: Comp1Component},
    {path: '/comp2', component: Comp2Component}
])
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

    heading: string = this.dataService.getHeading();
}
```

**Comp1Component**

```
import {DataService} from './DataService';

@Component({
    selector: 'comp1',
    providers: [DataService]
})
export class Comp1Component {
    // how to change heading property of app component from here
    // Want to change heading property of AppComponent to "Component 1"
    constructor(dataService: DataService) { 
        dataService.setHeading('Component 1');
    }
}
```

**Comp2Component**

```
import {DataService} from './DataService';

@Component({
    selector: 'comp2',
    providers: [DataService]
})
export class Comp2Component {
    // how to change heading property of app component from here
    // Want to change heading property of AppComponent to "Component 2"
    constructor(dataService: DataService) { 
        dataService.setHeading('Component 2');
    }
}
```

You can change the `heading` wherever you want, just keep in mind that if you need to do that outside of component constructor, the injected instance of `DataService` needs to be defined as `private` or be assigned to a class property.

Comment: Thanks Hani, I know that will surely work. But is there any native API in angular2 for child parent communication ... if I am using that as a directive, I know I can use @Output property for communicating with host but with routing component is there any Angular native API exists ?

Comment: @microchip78 not that i know of and it doesn't make sense for one to be there. Essentially all of your scenarios are doable using services and event emitters. Additionally, in future you don't need to do much if a new component 3 is added.

Comment: I tried with this approach, whenever component instantiated `setHeading` being called and update the variable inside the service but `getHeading` is not being called ? I have bind heading property exactly the same way you bind it here in this example ... any idea ??

Comment: Thanks @Hani. I got an idea from your suggestion and something I worked it out in Angular 1.x before.

Answer (score 0):

Above suggested way didn't work for me but I made it working using model inside the service and binding model property to parent component element.

This is working like a charm. :)

**SharedService.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

    data: any;          // you can create your own class but here just to understand data

    setHeading(newValue) {
        this.data.heading = newValue;
    }
}
```

**AppComponent.ts**

```
import {SharedService} from './SharedService';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    providers: [SharedService],
    template: `
        <div class="heading">{{sharedData.heading}}</div>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
@Routes([
    {path: '/comp1', component: Comp1Component},
    {path: '/comp2', component: Comp2Component}
])
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

    sharedData = this.sharedService.data;
}
```

**Comp1Component.ts**

```
import {SharedService} from './SharedService';

@Component({
    selector: 'comp1'       // you dont need to set providers for service, it will consume one from parent component
})
export class Comp1Component {
    constructor(sharedService: SharedService) { 
        sharedService.setHeading('Component 1');
    }
}
```

**Comp2Component.ts**

```
import {SharedService} from './SharedService';

@Component({
    selector: 'comp2'      // you dont need to set providers for service, it will consume one from parent component
})
export class Comp2Component {
    constructor(sharedService: SharedService) { 
        sharedService.setHeading('Component 2');
    }
}
```